# Filtering on child properties in GraphQL

Tags: 8

I am using GraphQL to get a list of upcoming events. I am having trouble finding the correct way to filter on the date `value` which is a child of my date field.

The query, which works:

```
query getUpcomingEvents {
  nodeQuery(
    filter: {
      conditions: [
        {operator: EQUAL, field: "type", value: ["ain_event"]},
        {operator: EQUAL, field: "status", value: ["1"]} 
      ]
    }
  )
  {
    entities {
      entityLabel
      ...on NodeAinEvent {
        fieldAinEventLocation
        fieldAinEventDate {
          startDate
          endDate
        }
        fieldAinLink {
          uri
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this response:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "nodeQuery": {
      "entities": [
        {
          "entityLabel": "EAA AIRVENTURE",
          "fieldAinEventLocation": "OshKosh, WI",
          "fieldAinEventDate": {
            "startDate": "2021-07-26 12:00:00 UTC",
            "endDate": "2021-08-01 12:00:00 UTC"
          },
          "fieldAinLink": {
            "uri": "http://www.eaa.org/en/airventure"
          }
        },
        {
          "entityLabel": "FlightSimExpo",
          "fieldAinEventLocation": "San Diego, CA",
          "fieldAinEventDate": {
            "startDate": "2021-09-24 12:00:00 UTC",
            "endDate": "2021-09-26 12:00:00 UTC"
          },
          "fieldAinLink": {
            "uri": "http://www.flightsimexpo.com/"
          }
        },
        {
          "entityLabel": "Sun 'n Fun",
          "fieldAinEventLocation": "Lakeland, FL",
          "fieldAinEventDate": {
            "startDate": "2020-03-31 12:00:00 UTC",
            "endDate": "2020-04-05 12:00:00 UTC"
          },
          "fieldAinLink": {
            "uri": "https://www.flysnf.org/"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding this, to no avail:

```
{operator: GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, field: "fieldAinEventDate.startDate", value: ["2021-07-25 12:00:00 UTC"]}
```

Comment: It's not a date range or anything is it? Is "value" the right property?

Comment: @Kevin see edit - and the error I get is just "Internal Server Error"

Comment: What is the logged error?

Comment: Well I am running this in Drupal's GraphiQL Explorer, so all I have is Watchdog indicating "Call to a member function getColumns() on bool"

Comment: This sounds related: https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/issues/710

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - apparently the fields are referenced differently in the filter conditions. This works:

```
{operator: GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, field: "field_ain_event_date", value: ["2021-07-25 12:00:00 UTC"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The important info here comes from [a comment](https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/issues/710#issuecomment-454773485) in the issue @Kevin referenced.

> You can only query the fields available on the entity.

This is because your query is eventually converted to an [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/9.2.x). You must reference fields and their properties as Drupal understands them, not how they're shown when returned from a GraphQL query.